# Excel Read to Text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to read everything in a worksheet in excel and assign it to a String variable.

```
Dim TextTxt as String   

'looping through worksheets to find worksheet "Card"

If Sheet.name = "Card" Then
                   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Card").Copy
End If
```

Above code copies the sheet, but how can I assign this to a text variable called "TextTxt". This TextTxt variable will be used to split and find the necessary strings later in this coding.

Comment: What you are doing is copying the worksheet (as you have noticed). Leave off the .copy and try it using .cells. Then you ofcourse need to assign it to an object that will store that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allows you to grab all the data on the sheet and store it in an object. This does not yet solve the output to a textfile part of your question.

**Updated answer**

```
Sub Test()
Dim TextTxt As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim sOutput As String

'looping through worksheets to find worksheet "Card"
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Card" Then
    Set TextTxt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Card").UsedRange
    For Each c In TextTxt
        sOutput = c.Value & "," & sOutput
    Next c
End If

MsgBox (sOutput)

End Sub
```

Comment: yes I am able to get everything in the sheet to TextTxt, but when I am trying to assign this to TxtPro String variable, it says type mismatch. How can I convert this TextTxt to String ?

Comment: what kind of string are you looking for in the output? you want every cell with content to be in one string? does the order the cells are in matter?

Comment: I want the entire cell value to be merged together as one entity. So basically, TextTxt will copy the value from the sheet and then pass it along to TxtPro as a single value.

Comment: then I think the answer now should do that if you make a function out of it